# Speed up foreach loop in perl

Tags: perl

I have a working perl script that scans a directory and uses imgsize 
http://dktools.sourceforge.net/imgsize.html to get the width, etc of png files.  Does anyone have any tips for speeding up this process (right now, it averages 5 minutes for every 1000 files)?  I was just wondering if the code could be optimized some how.  Thanks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my @files;
my $directory = '/Graphics/';
my $output_file = '/output_file';
my $max_height = 555;
my $count = 0;

open ( OUTPUT, '>>', $output_file );

find( \&wanted, $directory );

foreach my $file ( @files ) {
        if ( $file =~ /\.png$/ ) {
                my $height = `imgsize $file | cut -d\'\"\' -f4`;
                if ( $height > $max_height ) {
                        print OUTPUT "$file\n";
                }

                $count++;

                my $int_check = $count/1000;
                if ( $int_check !~ /\D/ ) {
                        print "processed: $count\n";
                }
        }
}

print "total: $count\n";
close ( OUTPUT );
exit;

sub wanted {
  push @files, $File::Find::name;
  return;
}
```

---

**Solution**: Turns out that I was able to use the `Image::Info` module.  I went from processing 1000 imgs every 5 minutes to every **12 seconds**.  Here's the relevant snippet of code, if anyone is interested:

```
 use Image::Info qw(image_info);

    foreach my $file ( @files ) {
            if ( $file =~ /\.png$/ ) {
                    my $output = image_info($file);
                    my $height = ${$output}{height};

                    if ($height > $max_height) {
                            print OUTPUT "$file\n";
                    }

                    $count++;

                    my $int_check = $count/1000;
                    if ( $int_check !~ /\D/ ) {
                            print "processed: $count\n";
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Have you profiled the script? [DeveL::NYTProf](http://p3rl.org/Devel::NYTProf) is great for profiling.

Comment: I assume that the bottleneck is the `imgsize` application. You could try to run multiple instances in parallel. See for example [Parallel::ForkManager](http://p3rl/Parallel::ForkManager)

Comment: Btw, strange $int_check. I'd write `if( $count%1000 == 0 )`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Perl code you've shown is likely not the culprit. You can profile it with [Devel::NYTProf](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-4.09/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm), just like @choroba has said. But I'd bet money that most of the time comes from forking two external processes per image (`imgsize` and `cut`). You should look into Perl modules that can retrieve the image's height without running any external process. Modules like [Image::Info](http://search.cpan.org/~srezic/Image-Info-1.33/lib/Image/Info.pm) come to mind.

Comment: Yes, I probably should look into other modules.  One wrinkle that I neglected to mention is that these images contain no metadata which negates the possibility of Image::Info.

Comment: I don't know how `Image::Info` works internally, but each and every image needs to have at least its size stored in its headers. Otherwise it cannot be decoded (unless that information is stored externally, which it doesn't seem to be in your case). So if `Image::Info` doesn't work for your images then others should still be able to parse those essential headers.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that about images, thanks for the additional info.

Comment: I used the `Image::Info` with dramatic improvement.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Launching external processes in a loop is usually a great way to make things go slowly. There's a significant cost to starting up another process, and if you're doing it for every image you're going to notice the cost pretty quickly. You're also calling `cut`, meaning it's two invocations for every time through the loop.

The first step would thus be to do the manipulation that `cut` does using native Perl string operations, and so eliminate one process startup per loop.

Unfortunately the only way to eliminate the process cost entirely is to do everything in-process, which means you need a library you can call from Perl which can read the images and get their sizes. I've not tried it, but `Perl::ImageMagick` might be worth looking at, and I'm sure there are others.

You could also try splitting your own process either with `fork` or threads and getting each child to do a portion of the load in parallel, but you might then run into issues with I/O availability on your system.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but no `Perl::ImageMagick` available for this, but clearly I could look into other modules.